# Работа с date() и cookies

Tags: php, дата, cookie

Есть 
**Current date:**  *09/20/2019 05:48*
и 
**Data end:** *09/21/2019 00:25*

Нужно в сессию записать срок даты.

Когда я отнимаю, то получаю ответ 0.

```
$date_current = date( 'm/d/Y h:i', time() );
$date_end    = $_COOKIE['end_date'] . ' ' . $_COOKIE['end_time'];
$formula = $date_end - $date_current;
echo "Data end: $date_end - Data current: $date_current = <b>" . $formula . "</b>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так время в секундах можно получить

```
$formula  = strtotime($date_end) - time()
```